# PHPUnit Stubbing A Method Call From Another Class

Tags: object, methods, phpunit, stub, stubbing

I have chosen PHPUnit to do some testing on a bot I built. This is the first example from the Test Doubles chapter:
`

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

final class StubTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testStub(): void
    {
        // Create a stub for the SomeClass class.
        $stub = $this->createStub(SomeClass::class);

        // Configure the stub.
        $stub->method('doSomething')
             ->willReturn('foo');

        // Calling $stub->doSomething() will now return
        // 'foo'.
        $this->assertSame('foo', $stub->doSomething());
    }
}
```

`

I see how doSomething() has been stubbed out, which is close to what I am trying to achieve.

How do I stub out an object method from another class that was created inside SomeClass::class?

Comment: it depends on how you are inject dependencies.

Comment: I am sorry. Maybe I was unclear. The method call I am stubbing is created in doSomething(). It is created/instantiated in doSomething(). Is this still considered to be dependency injection?

Comment: If its created with new() - its bad not tested design. If its created by factory - its about factory injection

Comment: so all i do is create this factory pattern object like you have suggested(i used this article as an example of a factory: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) and then inject it into SomeClass::class constructor? this factory that is passed to the constructor will be available to doSomething(). now i can stub out calls from another class because i selected them from the factory. does this make sense?